# Как избежать затирания табличных полей в документе?

Tags: php, битрикс24

Доброго времени суток гуру битрикса! Помогите кто чем может.
Создаётся документ в сделке:

```
$entity_id = $Deal["ID"]; //id Сделки
$template = \Bitrix\DocumentGenerator\Template::loadById($template_id);
$template->setSourceType(\Bitrix\Crm\Integration\DocumentGenerator\DataProvider\Deal::class);
$document = \Bitrix\DocumentGenerator\Document::createByTemplate($template, $entity_id); ......
```

В нём есть табличные данные:

```
......
'ProductName' => ['VALUE' => 'Table.Item.Name'],
'ProductCost' => ['VALUE' => 'Table.Item.Cost'],
'ProductNds' => ['VALUE' => 'Table.Item.Nds'],
'ProductCount' => ['VALUE' => 'Table.Item.Count'],
'ProductPercent' => ['VALUE' => 'Table.Item.Percent'],
'ProductReward' => ['VALUE' => 'Table.Item.Reward'],
......
```

Всё замечательно создаётся и сохраняется где нужно, но! При правке документа в сделке через стандартный интерфейс, все табличные поля затираются.
Была попытка исключить их из формы редактирования через инъекцию кода в компонент:

```
**crm.document.view**
```

Поля из редактирования пропали, но по прежнему затираются.
Так же была попытка заново подсунуть табличные данные в событие:

```
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler('documentgenerator', 'onUpdateDocument', function(\Bitrix\Main\Event $event)
///////////////////////////
$result = $document->getFile();
$res_data = $result->getData();
```

**$res_data** - рапортует что всё удачно добавилось, но!
Аналогично без результата, поля затираются.
Как можно этого избежать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну собственно сам спросил сам и отвечу :-)
Используем событие **\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler( "documentgenerator", "onBeforeProcessDocument", ["PreGenerationDocx", "onBeforeProcessDocument"]);**
И в нём перезаписываем табличные данные.